# Sum of two unitary matrix is equal to every matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R=M_{n}(Z_{2})$, can we write every matrices of $R$ as sum of two matrices of $GL_{n}(Z_{2})$?

Comment: The body of the question is unclear and doesn't correspond to the title. 

Comment: However, if a question like this appears unclear, I would rather ask the questioner to clarify it. In the present case, the only unclear point seems to me the use of "unitary" in the title, in place of "invertible". 

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are asking whether $R$ is a 2-good ring.  The answer is yes.  You may find the paper "2-good rings" by Peter Vamos to be useful in giving you some background information.

Comment: The answer is "yes" if all matrices are the sum of at most 2 units.
The answer is "almost" if every matrix is required to be the sum of exactly two units. (Hint: the monkey in this wrench is pretty small.) Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.08.24

Comment: I failed to remark that I am, of course, assuming that $n>1$, otherwise the result is not true. I also want to mention that a colleague of mine Thomas Dorsey (along with two coauthors) has a preprint on this topic which is quite good.  You might look for that paper to appear soon.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the preprint.  If you see the paper before I do, please mention it here.  I shall do same if I see the paper before a new comment here.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.08.24